# After a successful payment, What hook is triggered in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, to send sms payment information to the customer, I need to activate a trigger after a successful payment.

But I didn't find any hook do it

This is my plugin code:

```
if ( isset( $this->options['wc_notify_customer_payment_successful_enable'] ) ) {
    add_action( '####Action to be used here#######', array( &$this, 'successful_payment_notification_client' ) );
}

/* WooCommerce Successful payment notification client 
 *
 * @param $order_id
 */
public function successful_payment_notification_client ( $order_id ) {
    // Check the mobile field is empty
    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['mobile'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $order          = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $this->sms->to  = array( $_REQUEST['mobile'] );
    $template_vars  = array(
        '%order_id%'           => $order_id,
        '%order_number%'       => $order->get_order_number(),
        '%status%'             => $order->get_status(),
        '%billing_first_name%' => $_REQUEST['billing_first_name'],
        '%billing_last_name%'  => $_REQUEST['billing_last_name'],
        '%transaction_id%'     => get_post_meta( $order_id,'_payment_method_title', true ),
    );
    $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['wc_notify_customer_payment_successful_message'] );
    $this->sms->msg = $message;
    $this->sms->SendSMS();
}
```

The desired hook should come in line two of my code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to use **`woocommerce_payment_complete`** action hook that is just made specifically for that and located in [`WC_Order` `payment_completed()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#122). It's triggered jus after a successful payment. So try:

```
if ( isset( $this->options['wc_notify_customer_payment_successful_enable'] ) ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', array( &$this, 'successful_payment_notification_client' ) );
}
```

> You should try also to replace `array( &$this,` by `array( $this,` instead.

Or using **`woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status_processing`** hook:

```
if ( isset( $this->options['wc_notify_customer_payment_successful_enable'] ) ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status_processing', array( &$this, 'successful_payment_notification_client' ) );
}
```

> You should try also to replace `array( &$this,` by `array( $this,` instead.

or using `woocommerce_order_status_processing` hook *(but with 2 arguments: `$order_id` and `$order`)*:

```
if ( isset( $this->options['wc_notify_customer_payment_successful_enable'] ) ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', array( &$this, 'successful_payment_notification_client' ) );
}
```

> You should try also to replace `array( &$this,` by `array( $this,` instead.

Code goes in your plugin file…

---

> If there is no constructor (like for a class) or no instantiated object, you should use `add()` action function this way:
>
> ```
>  add_action( 'the_hook', 'the_hooked_function', $priority, $nb_of_args );
> ```

Comment: Hello tnx
I tried this ( woocommerce_payment_complete ) but did not answer
For example, try this ( woocommerce_new_order ) and send a message before buying and I make sure the codes work properly.

Can I connect it to an action that sends the order information to e-mail?
Because the email is sent after the payment is completed.

Comment: Thank you. After successful payment, it changes (in progress).

Comment: :-) yes , "processing"

Comment: The above items did not work....... A friend told me that he has three ways.... 1- Give the last priority to Hook  2-cron job   3- Put that hook in wp hook. (add_action('wp', ...)  ....... what is your opinion ?

Comment: You didn't tell in your question what it was really for. 1) In a plugin or a class, with a constructor you use `add_action( 'the_hook',  array( $this, 'the_hooked_function' ) )`… 2) If there is no constructor (or class or instantiated object) you use `add_action( 'the_hook',  'the_hooked_function' )`… Now there is some missing things like the priority and the number of arguments that the hooked function has. So you should try every possibility as you don't really know what you are doing.

Comment: After payment, an email is sent to the customer. Does not connect to email hook?

Comment: @MiladKarimi You can try it but this is not the way to do it. If it doesn't work with my answer hooks, it will not with any other…

Answer (score 0):

```
 add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete','this_is_custom_function');
 function this_is_custom_function($order_id){
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
 }
```

use "woocommerce_payment_complete" hook