# WooCommerce successful order hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am trying to send an email on success order so I was using until now the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook which seems to work perfect. But I found out that it is triggerred even when a customer tries to pay to external payment gateway (credit card payment), even though the payment is not accepted by the bank.

Which hook can I use in order to cover all these cases?

Bank Transfer, COD, Credit cart (only in succesfull payment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On successful paid orders for all payment gateways *others than Bank wire, cheque  or Cash on delivery,* you can use dedicated [`woocommerce_payment_complete` hook located in `WC_Order` `payment_complete()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.0/includes/class-wc-order.php#L121) instead of more generic hook `woocommerce_thankyou`, like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'action_payment_complete', 10, 2 );
function action_payment_complete( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Here add your code
}
```

Note that you can use defined `$order_id` and `$order` function arguments. Also this hook is only triggered once, avoiding repetitions.

---

**For Bank wire (bacs), Cheque (cheque) or Cash on delivery (cod)** payment methods, As the shop manager confirm manually that order is paid by changing order status, you can use the dedicated hook `woocommerce_order_status_changed` as follows.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'bacs_cheque_cod_payment_complete', 10, 4 );
function bacs_cheque_cod_payment_complete( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
    // 1. For Bank wire and cheque payments
    if( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), array('bacs', 'cheque') )
    && in_array( $new_status, wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ) ) {
        // Do something
    } 

    // 2. For Cash on delivery payments
    if( 'cod' === $order->get_payment_method() && 'completed' === $new_status ) {
        // Do something
    } 
}
```

Note that you can use defined `$order_id` and `$order` function arguments. Also this hook will be triggered once, on order status change, avoiding repetitions.

---

**Related:** [After a successful payment, What hook is triggered in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464499/after-a-successful-payment-what-hook-is-triggered-in-woocommerce/48468736#48468736)

Comment: well finally because I wanted to use only one hook, I kept the thank you one and I am checking if order has failed (which means that card payment didnt get through)

Comment: But I guess your solution is working too so I will accept this answer even though I am not using it

Comment: `&& ! $order->get_date_paid('edit')` should prevent the code for running a 2nd time if the order status changes from processing to completed. However, in my WC installation the `get_date_paid()' always retrieves a date and therefore the code never runs. Did something change in WC and that solution isn't working any more? Any hint for a new approach?

Comment: @mokorana Yes you are right, I have removed `&& ! $order->get_date_paid('edit')`…